# Stubbing with Ruby-on-Rails and MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, stub

I'm trying to understand how stubbing works with `Rails` and `MiniTest`. I've followed the simple example from [MiniTest documentation](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#stubs). I'm stuck with a very simple example:

```
require 'minitest/mock'
require "test_helper"

class TotoTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  class Clazz
    def foo
      "foo"
    end
  end

  test "Stubbing" do
    puts Clazz.new.foo # "foo" is well printed
    Clazz.stub :foo, "bar" do # ERROR HERE
      assert_equal "bar", Clazz.new.foo
    end
  end
end
```

When stubbing, I get an error telling the method `foo`. The full execution log:

```
Testing started at 13:55 ...
[...]
Started

foo

Minitest::UnexpectedError: NameError: undefined method `foo' for class `TotoTest::Clazz'
    test/models/toto_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:TotoTest>'
test/models/toto_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:TotoTest>'
Finished in 0.52883s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can't begin to understand why i'm told the `foo` method does not exist when the execution runs well the line before.

What am I missing? Why does this not work?

I've even tried an alternative, using a mock:

```
require 'minitest/mock'
require "test_helper"

class TotoTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  class Clazz
    def foo
      "foo"
    end
  end

  test "Stubbing" do
    mock = Minitest::Mock.new
    def mock.foo
      "bar"
    end

    puts Clazz.new.foo
    Clazz.stub :foo, mock do
      assert_equal "bar", Clazz.new.foo
    end
  end
end
```

The result is the same. Where am I wrong?

EDIT : Use case

To be more precise, I'd like to stub the YouTube API. The calls to YouTube API are implemented in a module. The module is included in a controller. In a system test, I'd like to replace the real call to that API by a stub, to be independent from YouTube API.

Comment: might want to look at [`webmock`](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) for stubbing HTTP requests. and maybe [`vcr`](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) if you would like to record a request and reuse it a bunch of times.

Comment: I better avoid using any dependency when not absolutely necessary (KISS). Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: Stubbing a web request is anything but simple. If it works for you tests, great, but there are a lot of nuances to web requests and if the spec ever changes for the YouTube api you are relying on your stubbed class will mask this over using a vcr recording that expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stubbing a class method instead of an instance method:

```
Clazz.stub :foo, "bar"
```

You call `stub` on an instance of `Class` class referenced by a constant `Clazz`.

You should call `#stub` on `Clazz` instance:

```
clazz = Clazz.new
clazz.stub :foo, mock do
  assert_equal "bar", clazz.foo
end
```

Edit:
Regarding the use case. I think that a controller is a wrong place to include methods handling an external API. I would suggest to wrap it in a separate object, then  you can stub this object, e.g.:

```
yt_mock = ... # mocking yt methods you want to use
YouTube.stub :new, yt_mock do
  # controler test
end
```

You can also create YouTube as a class that accepts adapters and delegates calls to them - one adapter would use a real YT api, another one just predefined answers.

Comment: Is there a way to stub all future instances of that class? In the documentation, there is something that lets me think this is possible: `Time.stub :now, Time.at(0) do`

Comment: There is a [gem](https://github.com/codeodor/minitest-stub_any_instance) that seems to be doing so. IMO Stubbing any instance may be a code smell and if you do it, you should probably reconsider your design.

Comment: Btw RSpec has methods for this: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance

Comment: You're right for the code smell. I'm not using `RSpec`, but `MiniTest`. I've updated my question with the real use case. Do you have any suggestion with these new elements?